# How can I disable setter generation without using final?

Tags: dart

For fun and to learn, I'm building a simple game engine with Dart. I have defined an abstract `Game` class. A `Game` has a `Director director` field which manages scene transitions. This class is also abstract. Each concrete game must implement its own concrete `Game` and `Director` classes, say `MyGame` and `MyDirector`.

I'm setting `Game`'s director like this:

```
abstract class Game {
  Director director;

  Game() {
    director = createDirector();
  }

  Director createDirector();
}
```

`MyGame` (which inherits from `Game`) implements `createDirector()`.

Using this approach Dart generates a setter for the `director` field so users of `Game` instances can change it like this `game.director = something;`. I don't want that to be possible. The usual way to solve this is to make the `director` field `final`, but I cannot do this because of how its assigned/created inside the `Game` constructor (and not the initialization list).

How can I disable the generation of the `director` setter in this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making it `final` is what's recommended but indeed you won't be able to assign to it in the constructor.

Alternatively you can do what the style guide considers unadvisable, wrap a private field with a getter without a setter:

```
abstract class Game {
  var _director;
  get director => _director;
}
```